# Can I tip Basic Attention Token (BAT) directly without using Brave Browser?

Tags: erc-20, addresses, basic-attention-token, brave-browser

From the [BAT FAQ](https://basicattentiontoken.org/FAQ/),

> **Explain the Brave and BAT products and how they work together.**
>
> [...] Whether you want to earn BAT by seeing ads, or buy tokens directly, you can use them to support the sites you visit, automatically or via direct tipping. [...]

It seems to have implicitly assumed that it's required to have Brave Browser installed in order for tipping / donation to work.

Can I donate to organizations registered as [Brave Rewards publishers](https://publishers.basicattentiontoken.org/) directly without using Brave Browser? Can I search for the BAT wallet address of a given publisher, and donate to that publisher directly using an (on-chain) transaction from my ERC-20 wallet?

If this on-chain tipping is not possible, is there an API for off-chain tipping? Can I be assured that the publisher really receive the donation? I don't want a middleman to take away my donation without me knowing.